# Dimension error while merging of data frames

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I was trying to implement `sm.OLS(y,x).fit()` on a dataset but the error states that y and x have varying lengths. Earlier in my code is x is derived from merging `data_prep_num = pd.merge(data_prep_num,data_prep_text_manual_onehot,right_index=True,left_index=True)` the dimension of `data_prep_num(after merging)` is `1458 X 81` where as the dimensions of `data_prep_num and data_prep_text_manual_onehot` is `1459 X x`.

If I can match the dimensions of both `x=data_prep_num` and `y=data_sales_price_old` then I guess this error can be resolved >ValueError: endog and exog matrices are different sizes.

Comment: What is your question, do you want to know how to resize the DataFrames?

Comment: I have two dataframes each has 1459 rows, when I am merging both of them the merged dataframe has 1458 rows. Thats the issue I am facing.

Comment: We need more information, then. If we don’t know how your DataFrames are built then nothing can be done. Could you post a [mcve]?